# How to apply code highlights within markdown-to-jsx package in react?

Tags: reactjs, markdown, jsx, syntax-highlighting

I'm using the markdown-to-jsx package in order to render documentation content inside my react project.
This package provides a Markdown component, which accepts an options prop to override HTML elements's default style, and more.

```
const markdownOptions = {
    wrapper: DocsContentWrapper, 
    forceWrapper: true,
    overrides: {
        h1: LeadTitle,
        h2: SecondaryTitle,
        h3: ThirdTitle,
        p: Paragraph, 
        pre: CodeWrapper,
        ol: ListWrapper,
        li: ListItem,
    },
};

<Markdown 
    options={MarkdownOptions}
>
    {MockDoc}
</Markdown>
```

Now, the Markdown component accept a markdown, so I pass it a string which is formatted accoring to markdown [rules](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/).

It contains some code blocks, like the following, which I want to add colors to:

[image]

I have created a  component using 'react-syntax-highlighter' package, and it looks like the following:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Prism as SyntaxHighlighter } from "react-syntax-highlighter"
import { tomorrow } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism"

const SyntaxHighligher = ({ language, markdown }) => {
    
    return (
        <SyntaxHighlighter 
            language={language} 
            style={tomorrow}
        >
            {markdown}
        </SyntaxHighlighter>
    );
};

export default SyntaxHighligher;
```

And here comes the question - how can I integrate the two?
I was thinking that it would have made sense if the options object would accept such configuration, but looking at 'markdown-to-jsx' [docs](https://github.com/probablyup/markdown-to-jsx/blob/master/README.md) via their GitHub page, shows no option.

I have seen a package called 'react-markdown' that is able to accept my SyntaxHighligher component and to the task, but I want to apply the same functionality with 'markdown-to-jsx' package.

Answer (score 4):

`markdown-to-jsx` generates code blocks as `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`, but we can't simply override `code` tag since inline code uses it as well. The README from `markdown-to-jsx` suggests that we can override `pre > code` somehow:

> Some element mappings are a bit different from other libraries, in particular:
>
> `span`: Used for inline text.
> `code`: Used for inline code.
> `pre > code`: Code blocks are a code element with a pre as its direct ancestor.

But based on my experiments and reading of the source code, I think the only way is to override `pre` and check for `code` in its `children`. For example:

```js
import {Prism as SyntaxHighlighter} from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import {materialDark as CodeStyle} from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism';

const CodeBlock = ({className, children}) => {
  let lang = 'text'; // default monospaced text
  if (className && className.startsWith('lang-')) {
    lang = className.replace('lang-', '');
  }
  return (
    <SyntaxHighlighter language={lang} style={CodeStyle}>
      {children}
    </SyntaxHighlighter>
  );
}

// markdown-to-jsx uses <pre><code/></pre> for code blocks.
const PreBlock = ({children, ...rest}) => {
  if ('type' in children && children ['type'] === 'code') {
    return CodeBlock(children['props']);
  }
  return <pre {...rest}>{children}</pre>;
};

const YourComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Markdown
      options={{
        overrides: {
          pre: PreBlock,
        },
      }}
    >
      {yourMarkdown}
    </Markdown>
  );
};
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a good solution if you want to override BOTH inline code and code blocks. When overriding both `pre` and `code` tags, the `code` tag generated by `SyntaxHighlighter` also gets overridden, so the inline code and code blocks are rendered identically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the OP. Here is my approach for it

```
import { PrismLight as SyntaxHighlighter } from "react-syntax-highlighter";
import { materialDark } from "react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/prism";
import Markdown from "markdown-to-jsx";

function Code({ className, children }) {
  const language = className.replace("lang-", "");
  return (
    <div className="codeBlock">
      <SyntaxHighlighter language={language.toLowerCase()} style={materialDark}>
        {children}
      </SyntaxHighlighter>
    </div>
  );
}

function JsxFromMarkdown() {
  return (
    <div className="markdownContainer">
      <Markdown
        options={{
          overrides: {
            code: {
              component: Code,
            },
          },
        }}
      >
        {markdownContent}
      </Markdown>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I use `language={language.toLowerCase()}` inside Code component as my code block in markdown file is written as ```PYTHON  a = 1 + 2 ```. If your code is written as ```python  a = 1 + 2 ``` inside markdown file, you should use `language={language}` inside Code component.